# Ajax call not responding on repeated request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a page with a dropdown.  The `onchange` event calls a Javascript function (below) that includes an Ajax block that retrieves data and populates a `TEXTAREA`.  On the surface, everything works.

I can select any item in the list with no problems.  However, if I select an item that has previously been selected, the Ajax call appears to hang.  It looks like maybe some weird caching issue or something.  If I close the browser and reload the page, all items work again until I re-select.

I've tested for the `readyState` and `status` properties when it's hanging, but I get nothing.  Am I missing something?

The page is a client project behind authentication so I can't post a URL, but here's the Ajax code.  This is in a PHP page, but there's no PHP script related to this.

```
function getText( id ) {
var txt = document.getElementById( "MyText" );

txt.disabled = "disabled";
txt.innerText = "";
txt.className = "busy";

var oRequest = zXmlHttp.createRequest();
oRequest.open( "get", "get_text.php?id=" + id, true );
oRequest.send( null );

oRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( oRequest.readyState == 4 ) {
        if( oRequest.status == 200 ) {
            txt.innerText = oRequest.responseText;
        } else {
            txt.innerText = oRequest.status + ": " + oRequest.statusText;   
        }

        txt.disabled = "";
        txt.className = "";

        oRequest = null;
    }
}}
```

*Edit:* The code block seems a little quirky; it won't let me include the final `}` unless it's on the same line as the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `onreadystatechange` function *after* you're sending the request. If it takes a long time (ie if it goes to the server), this will probably work, since there will be a delay before it tries to call the callback.

If the page is cached, though, the browser is probably trying to call `onreadystatechange` immediately in the `send` method. Move your assignment to `onreadystatechange` to before the `open/send` code.

Comment: +1: send should be the very last thing you do with your request

Answer (score 1):

HI, 
The caching is due to the same url thats being called repeatedly. If you change the URl dynamically then this issue can be rsolved. Something like by adding a querystring with the current time with the request ( or any random renerated number ) you can change the url without affecting the result

Comment: This technique has worked for me many times.  Add something like &zz=SomeRandomNumber to the end of your url so the url is unique each time you call it.  Then ignore the zz variable in your handler code.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you are running into a caching issue.  I have noticed that Internet Explorer is more aggressive at caching ajax calls than Firefox is.  One way to be sure of what is happening is to use Fiddler2.  This application monitors your web traffic, and you would be able to see if the browser is making a request or not, and what cache headers are coming back on the responses that you do get.

You can download fiddler2 from http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/